# to add unicode in android and phone?

Tags: java, android, xml, unicode, space

This is my activity

```
 String name =et.getText().toString();
            String a = "a";
            String a1 = "\u24B6";
            String b = "b";
            String b1 = "\u24B7";
            String c = "c";
            String c1 = "\u24B7";
            String d = "d";
            String d1 = "\u24B9";
            String e = "d";
            String e1 = "\u24BB";
            name = name.replaceAll(a,a1);
            name = name.replaceAll(b,b1);
            name = name.replaceAll(c,c1);
            name = name.replaceAll(d,d1);
            name = name.replaceAll(e,e1);
            tv.setText(name);
```

when write a or b or c in edittext show space in textview
what is solution?

Comment: Unclear. Could you please explain yourself better?

Comment: Try to use characters instead of Strings for the replacement

Answer (score 0):

Use a TextWatcher on your EditText.

```
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            et.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            // make changes to s here
            et.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: please comment for this code and where insert text view